# Select a method as (default) template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm developing a container template class. This code needs to interface with existing C code and needs to stay binary compatible, so I can not use i.e. `std::vector` or similar.

The problem that I have is that it needs to support different allocation strategies, and I don't know how to provide the allocator as a template argument. I created an `SSCCE`  to illustrate how far I got (which of course doesn't compile, because if it would, I wouldn't need to ask this question :)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

typedef unsigned int        uint_t;
typedef signed int          int_t;

template <typename T, typename S, typename _allocator = _virtual>
class Container
{
public:
    Container(S nItems = 0, S nMaxItems = 0, T *pArray = NULL)
    {
        mItems = nItems;
        mMaxItems = nMaxItems;
        mArray = pArray;
    }

    void adjustMalloc(uint_t nClusterSize)
    {
        if(mItems == mMaxItems)
        {
            mArray = (T *)realloc(mArray, (mMaxItems+nClusterSize)*sizeof(T));
            mMaxItems += nClusterSize;
        }
    }

    void adjustAligned(uint_t nClusterSize)
    {
        if(mItems == mMaxItems)
        {
            mArray = (T *)_aligned_realloc(mArray, (mMaxItems+nClusterSize)*sizeof(T), 16);
            mMaxItems += nClusterSize;
        }
    }

    void adjustVirtual(uint_t nClusterSize)
    {
        if(mItems == mMaxItems)
        {
            mArray = VirtualAlloc(mArray, (mMaxItems+nClusterSize)*sizeof(T), MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_NOACCESS);
            mMaxItems += nClusterSize;
        }
    }

    void adjust(uint_t nClusterSize)
    {
        if (std::is_same<_allocator>::value == _virtual)
            adjustVirtual(nClusterSize);
        else if(std::is_same<_allocator>::value == _aligned)
            adjustAligned(nClusterSize);
        else if(std::is_same<_allocator>::value == _malloc)
            adjustMalloc(nClusterSize);
        else
        {
            // Cause a static compiler error, how?
        }
    }

    bool add(T *pItem)
    {
        if(find(pItem) == NULL)
        {
            adjust(100);
            mItems++;

            return true;    // added
        }

        return false;
    }

    T *find(T *pItem)
    {
        T *p = mArray;

        for(S i = 0; i < mItems; i++, p++)
        {
            if(*p == *pItem)
                return p;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

private:
    S mItems;
    S mMaxItems;
    T *mArray;
};


class Record
{
public:

    bool operator==(const Record &oRecord)
    {
        if(Id != oRecord.Id)
            return false;

        if(strcmp(Name, oRecord.Name) != 0)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    int Id;
    char Name[10+1];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Record rec;
    rec.Id = 0;
    strcpy(rec.Name, "Test");

    Container<Record, uint_t> records;   // Default using malloc
    records.add(&rec);

    if(records.find(&rec) == NULL)
        std::cerr << "Not found" << std::endl;

    Container<Record, uint_t, _virtual> vrecords;   // VirtualAlloc allocator used.
    vrecords.add(&rec);

    if(records.find(&rec) == NULL)
        std::cerr << "Not found" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 so it's not 100% C++11.

The `VirtualAlloc` is provided just as (another) example and will not work as it is shown here.

Comment: How does reimplementing `vector` solve your interface problem?

Comment: Is this relevant for an answer?

Comment: Yes. Right now your `Container` has several problems, so I would like to understand what this approach actually gets you that just using `vector` doesn't (or really `std::set`, based on what `add` does)

Comment: I already mentioned in the text that I need to stay binary compatible with existing C code, so I can write a wrapper that provides a nicer interface for new code, but must also ensure that old code works without being changed.

Comment: Why don't you define an interface, a different allocators which comply to that and do the different mallocs, and simply call them ? In fact, I think you could do that only with OOP, no need for templates.

Comment: @perencia, and how do you propose to handle different structures, if not using a template?

Comment: @Devolus To handle different structures you just need a common interface and polymorphism. Anyway i was not referring to the structures that you were to handle, but to the allocator. Moreover, i think defining the allocator as a template parameter is fine. I read about that in Modern C++ programming, maybe you should take a look at it...

Comment: @perencia, in the original code (not shown here) the allocator manipulates the container, so it needs to be part of it or must at least know about it. I don't know how to handle that, with the container template, because the container can have different size types and i would need an allocator for each possible type in order to do that.

Comment: @perencia, actually, i was modelling this template after the vector because it is very similar. I already found now a solution for my problem, just have some annyoing warnings.

Comment: @Devolus Ok, I understand :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. However, I get warnings

`warning C4127: conditional expression is constant`

in the `adjust()` method for the `if(std::is_same...` and I was wondering if this is normal or if I can get rid of it, other than disabling it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

#pragma warning (push)
//#pragma warning (disable : 4127)

typedef unsigned int        uint_t;
typedef signed int          int_t;

typedef struct { const static bool _virtual_allocator = true; } _virtual_type;
typedef struct { const static bool _aligned_allocator = true; } _aligned_type;
typedef struct { const static bool _malloc_allocator = true; } _malloc_type;

template <typename T, typename S, typename _allocator = _aligned_type>
class Container
{
public:
    Container(S nItems = 0, S nMaxItems = 0, T *pArray = NULL)
    {
        mItems = nItems;
        mMaxItems = nMaxItems;
        mArray = pArray;
    }

    void adjustMalloc(uint_t nClusterSize)
    {
        if(mItems == mMaxItems)
        {
            mArray = (T *)realloc(mArray, (mMaxItems+nClusterSize)*sizeof(T));
            mMaxItems += nClusterSize;
        }
    }

    void adjustAligned(uint_t nClusterSize)
    {
        if(mItems == mMaxItems)
        {
            mArray = (T *)_aligned_realloc(mArray, (mMaxItems+nClusterSize)*sizeof(T), 16);
            mMaxItems += nClusterSize;
        }
    }

    void adjustVirtual(uint_t nClusterSize)
    {
        if(mItems == mMaxItems)
        {
            mArray = (T *)VirtualAlloc((LPVOID)mArray, (mMaxItems+nClusterSize)*sizeof(T), MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_NOACCESS);
            mMaxItems += nClusterSize;
        }
    }

    void adjust(uint_t nClusterSize)
    {
        if (std::is_same<_allocator, _virtual_type>::value)
            adjustVirtual(nClusterSize);
        else if(std::is_same<_allocator, _aligned_type>::value)
            adjustAligned(nClusterSize);
        else if(std::is_same<_allocator, _malloc_type>::value)
            adjustMalloc(nClusterSize);
        else
        {
            // Cause a static compiler error, how?
        }
    }

    bool add(T *pItem)
    {
        if(find(pItem) == NULL)
        {
            adjust(100);
            mItems++;

            return true;    // added
        }

        return false;
    }

    T *find(T *pItem)
    {
        T *p = mArray;

        for(S i = 0; i < mItems; i++, p++)
        {
            if(*p == *pItem)
                return p;
        }

        return NULL;
    }

private:
    S mItems;
    S mMaxItems;
    T *mArray;
};

#pragma warning (pop)

class Record
{
public:
    bool operator==(const Record &oRecord)
    {
        if(Id != oRecord.Id)
            return false;

        if(strcmp(Name, oRecord.Name) != 0)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    int Id;
    char Name[10+1];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Record rec;
    rec.Id = 0;
    strcpy(rec.Name, "Test");

    Container<Record, uint_t> mrecords;
    mrecords.add(&rec);

    if(mrecords.find(&rec) == NULL)
        std::cerr << "Malloc Not found" << std::endl;

    Container<Record, uint_t, _aligned_type> arecords;
    arecords.add(&rec);

    if(arecords.find(&rec) == NULL)
        std::cerr << "Aligned Not found" << std::endl;

    Container<Record, uint_t, _virtual_type> vrecords;
    vrecords.add(&rec);

    if(vrecords.find(&rec) == NULL)
        std::cerr << "Virtual Not found" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```